# I am trying to print Crystal Report "bill.rpt" could not print or save as a PDF to my development environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using Windows XP SP3, Crystal Reports Basic version 10.5.3700.0 (followed by c:\windows\assembly), Visual Studio 2008, MSSQL 2008 R2.

Error

> Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\NKT\LOCALS~1\Temp\Bill {CE9EC584-2281}.rpt:

Error description

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error in File C:\DOCUME~1\NKT\LOCALS~1\Temp\Bill
    {CE9EC584-2281-4C5F-89ED-54C60AFCC0CB}.rpt:
        The table could not be found.
```

Source Error:

```
Line 2697:               myReportDocument.SetDataSource(ds); Line
2698:               //myReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, true,0,0);
Line 2699:               myReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);

Source File: c:\Documents and Settings\NKT\My Documents\Visual
Studio 2008\Projects\\ParlerBill.aspx.cs    Line: 2699
```

Here is my .cs file code snippet

```
//--Opening Sql Connection
String strConn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strCmd, sqlConn);
sqlConn.Open();

//--this statement is very important, here the table name should match with the XML Schema table name. 
da.Fill(ds, "customerbilldetail");

//--Closing Sql Connection
sqlConn.Close();

//--(Optional) I have used it to disable the properties
CrystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;
CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = false;
CrystalReportViewer1.HasCrystalLogo = false;

//--Initializing CrystalReport
ReportDocument myReportDocument;
myReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
myReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~//Repport/Bill.rpt"));
myReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "saa");
myReportDocument.SetDataSource(ds);
//myReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, true,0,0);
myReportDocument.PrintToPrinter(1, false, 0, 0);
```

Here the error is throwing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://community.ivanti.com/docs/DOC-23965), this can be caused by having a table owner mismatch between the attribute in the report and the table in the database.

Comment: As far as your concern helped me @Mario .